# Python Issue Making a Game

Tags: python, python-2.7, customization

Im a new python learner and Im reading Zed Shaw book called : 
Learn python the hardway 
Im doing very well at following the instructions and doing the study drills as well .
Recently I've tried to make a little game by myself but i got stuck and i need a little help
this is my script :

```
from sys import exit

def starting():
    print "Welcome to the abyss of dark"
    print "The game is about choosing"
    print "if you lose you die if you win you live"

    choose_door = raw_input("> ")

    if "1" in choose_door or "door 1" or "D1" or "d1":
        no_weapon()
    elif "2" in choose_door or "door 2" or "D2" or "d2":
        Weapon_room()
    elif "3" in choose_door or "door 3" or "D3" or "d3":
        shortcut()
    elif "4" in choose_door or "door 4" or "D4" or "d4":
        princess_room()
    elif "5" in choose_door or "door 5" or "D5" or "d5":
        princess_room()
    elif "6" in choose_door or "door 6" or "D6" or "d6":
        gards_room()
    else:
        "7" in choose_door or "door7" or "D7" or "d7"
        suicide_room()

start()

def map():
    print """"
    |------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
    |   shortcut     D|room of the | room of the|                                        |
    |     to D4      O|princess    | gards      | S U I C I D E      R O  O M            |
    |                O|            |            |                                        |
    |                R|            |            |                                        |
    |                4|            |            |                                        |
    |-----DOOR 3---|------DOOR 5-------DOOR 6---------------------DOOR 7----------------|
    |Weapon ROOM |                                                                      |
    |            | DOOR 2               YOUR                                            |
    |            |                            ARE                                       |
    |            |                                 HERE                                 |
    |------------|                                                                      |
    |No Weapon   | DOOR 1                                                               |
    |            |                                                                      |
    |------------|------------------------------------------------------------------------

    """
    start()

def no_weapon():
    print "You've choosed to continue with no Weapons"
    print "What a BRAVE PLAYER!"
    print "Choose your door"
    print "3 , 5 , 6 , 7"
    no_weapon_door = raw_input("> ")
    if no_weapon_door == "3":
        shortcut
    elif no_weapon_door == "5":
        princess_room
    elif no_weapon_door == "6":
        gards_room
    else:
        suicide_room



def Weapon_room():
    print "You are armed now"
    print "Which door you choose type just the number"
    print "Door 3 or Door 4"
    Weapon_room_door = raw_input("> ")
    if Weapon_room_door == "3":
        shortcut
    else:
        princess_room

def shortcut():
    princess_room

def princess_room():
    print "You won"

def gards_room():
    print "fight with gards"
    print "Yes or No"
    fighting = raw_input("> ")
    if fighing == "Yes":
            princess_room
    else:
        fighting == "No"
        lost
def suicide_room():
    print "Die in peace"
    lost

def lost():
    print "You lost"
    print "If you want to reapeat Press R if you wanna exit tye E"
    losing = raw_input ("> ")
    if losing == "R":
        start()
    else:
        exit()
```

for me i think everything i written as it should be but when i run my script i get an error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "newgame.py", line 26, in 
    start()
NameError: name 'start' is not defined
```

couldn't figure out 
Help me Please and thank you

Comment: It looks like the function is called `starting()` but you are running `start()`, so simply change your 3rd line to `def start():`.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably fix the formatting of your code, but I believe you meant to put starting() instead of start() because you don't have a method named start().

Answer (score 0):

You can actually rename your starting function into "start", because you are calling the start func

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to call `starting()` function, and in place of that you mistakenly called `start()` which is nowhere defined in the entire program.

So, either name the 1st function in the programme as `start()` or else rename the 3 occurrences of `start()` to `starting()`.